# Migrating Spring Boot application to Quarkus using JPA and JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

Good afternoon, I'm new to Quarkus and I'm migrating a Spring Boot application, specifically a microservice that performs a DB query through a Procedure, to Quarkus using JPARepository, however I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.spring.data.deployment.UnableToParseMethodException: Method 'findDataxMovil' of repository 'com.tmve.subscriber.repositories.FindAccountNumberRepository' cannot b
e parsed as there is no proper 'By' clause in the name.
```

My Repository and Entity classes are defined as follows, just like in Spring Boot:

**AccountNumber**

```
package com.tmve.subscriber.entities;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "buscar_datos_x_movil", procedureName = "PERS.PKG_LCL_CUENTA.BUSCAR_DATOS_X_MOVIL", resultClasses = AccountNumber.class, parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_movil", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_fecha_operacion", type = Date.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "p_lista", type = AccountNumber.class) }) })
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class AccountNumber implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID= 1L;

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column (name= "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="APELLIDO")
    private String apellido;

    @Column(name ="SE")
    private String se;

    @Column(name = "NUMERO_DOC_PRINCIPAL")
    private String numeroDocPrincipal;

    @Column(name = "ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO")
    private String idTipoDocumento;

    @Column(name = "TIPO")
    private String tipo;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_NAC")
    private String fechaNac;

    @Column(name = "ID_CICLO_CONTROL")
    private String idCicloControl;

    @Column(name = "ID_MARCA")
    private String idMarca;

    @Column(name = "ID_MODELO")
    private String idModelo;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_MARCA")
    private String nombreMarca;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_MODELO")
    private String nombreModelo;

    @Column(name = "ESN")
    private String esn;

    @Column(name = "NUMERO_MOVIL")
    private String numeroMovil;

    @Column(name = "ID_CUENTA_PAGADORA")
    private String idCuentaPagadora;

    @Column(name = "ID_CUENTA_USO")
    private String idCuentaUso;

}
```

**FindAccountNumberRepository**

```
package com.tmve.subscriber.repositories;

import com.tmve.subscriber.entities.AccountNumber;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public interface FindAccountNumberRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountNumber,String> {

    @Procedure(name = "buscar_datos_x_movil")
    ResultSet findDataxMovil(@Param("p_movil") String movil, @Param("p_fecha_operacion") Date fechaOperacion);

}
```

**Application.Properties**

```
quarkus.datasource.username=APP_MS_PERS_DEV
quarkus.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@1xxxxxxxxx:1531/PERSDES
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
```

That could be happening? It seems that it is taking the procedure as a Query from the fields of the Entity

Is there another method that could be applied?

Comment: `@Procedure` is not yet supported in the Quarkus version of Spring Data JPA. Feel free to open an issue on GitHub asking for this feature

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Can it work procedure with Panache Framework?

Comment: There is no explicit support in `Panache`, but you can obtain JPA's `EntityManager` from Panache and use it to execute a stored procedure.